# Multiple Verticle deployement on different port in Vert.x Clustered env. issue

Tags: hazelcast, vert.x, sockjs, event-bus

> I have Main verticle deploying other verticles on different port:

```
 public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {

     ...

     final DeploymentOptions frontOptions = new DeploymentOptions()
            .setInstances(Configuration.HZ_NB_INSTANCES_NOTIFICATION);

     final DeploymentOptions backOptions = new DeploymentOptions()
            .setInstances(Configuration.HZ_NB_INSTANCES_NOTIFICATION);


     ...

    ClusterManager mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager();
    VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions().setClusterManager(mgr);

    Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {

     vertx.deployVerticle(WebVerticle.class.getName(), frontOptions, 
         deployResult -> {
                  if (deployResult.succeeded()) {                                           
                       vertx.deployVerticle(SockVerticle.class.getName(), 
                  backOptions , deployResult1 -> {

                  ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

> Where WebVerticle is used to create a `Vert.x Web Server` , it will host all static files on 8090 (httpServer).
>
> And SockVerticle is used to create an EventBus using SockJSHandler on 8091(httpServer).

Sometimes when we load application it fails to process received message on eventbus, so i have to do hard refresh in chrome.

Should I create two different fat.jar for web (static pages) exposed on httpServer ( 8090 ) and eventbus exposed on httpServer ( 8091 )(backend operation) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to update my java arguments for clustering :

> run com.xxx.MainVerticle --launcher-class=io.vertx.core.Launcher --conf=xxx.json -Dvertx.options.blockedThreadCheckInterval=200000000 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp . -cluster